# несколько carousel Bootstrap на странице

Tags: html, slider, bootstrap4

На странице есть 2 слайдера на чистом бутстрапе (без изменения js и прочего). Нужно чтобы оба слайдера перелистывались одновременно. По сути в 8 из 10 раз это работает правильно (как мне надо), но иногда что-то происходит и один из слайдеров (рандомный) перелистывается с задержкой.

Как это исправить? Любые методы.

data-interval ставил одиннаковый, всё равно в 2/10 случаев ломается логика. Хелп.

Comment: покажите код слайдера и код jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию в карусели параметру pause задано значение hover - при любом, даже мимолётном, проходе мыши над слайдером он притормаживает. Отсюда и рассинхрон.

Попробуйте добавить каруселям атрибут data-pause="false".

Comment: Спасибо, да вы правы. Исправил - помогло. Код не скинул ибо мой слайдер нагружен контентом, а так это был обычный слайдер использующий стандартные правила.